# How to prevent hotlinking static files?

Tags: jetty, jetty-9

I want to prevent hotlinking on my static files on a Jetty 9.3.6 server, that is to only allow my domain, my subdomains, and directly access (none referer header, such as open it directly with the url on a web browser) to view  them.

The only thing I've found so far is `HeaderPatternRule` of the Rewrite pluggin but seems like it can only rewrite the header.

Do you know how? Understanding I can have something in front of the Jetty server to do the work for it.

Update: Something like this on Apache Httpd

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www.)?yourwebdomain.com(/)?.*$ [NC]
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a Filter to your static deployment protecting your preferred paths from hot linking.

See prior answer with example filter: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4051622/775715